# Faster ar_track_alvar

Tags: ros, markers, ar-track-alvar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm playing around with ar_track_alvar package. I use it both to initialize amcl and to localize the docking station.

It works fine, but is a terrible CPU-hunger. I have changed the code to limit its frequency, but even at 8 Hz it's always taking around 60% of CPU, and my navi stack is suffering CPU starvation (and the laptop eventually switch off!).

Any suggestion for reducing the CPU usage? Maybe I should try the non-kinect version, but really I need a good depth estimation.

Another idea i'm thinking about is to make it a nodelet and load on the kinect nodelet manager... not sure if this helps reducing CPU usage, but I'm afraid it can slow down the fake laserscan.

Thank you a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60639/faster-ar_track_alvar/) by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2284 on 2013-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, this is not a solution, but I added dynamic reconfiguration with an enable/disable switch that subscribes/unsubscribes to pointcloud topic, what at the same time stops the (also very CPU-hungry) depth image to pointcloud nodelet. My fork https://github.com/corot/ar_track_alvar.git

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0